# Unable to write streamed data to sink file using Spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create data flow pipeline using spring cloud data flow using shell(Not UI). Source being twitterstream and sink as File. Here is what i did to configure file-sink :

`dataflow:>stream create demo --definition "twitterstream --credentials | file --dir=/opt/datastream --mode=APPEND --filename=tweets.txt"`

I can consume data from kafka topic but unable to write on above sink location, file is not even created . NO error log while deploying the stream. Eventually i will change it to HDFS from local file system. Is there anything missing ?

PS: I tried default file-sink (without definition), which is supposed to create default file inside /tmp/xd/output,  didn't happen either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the latest [1.0.0.RELEASE](https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/12/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-0-ga-released) (GA) release, the following stream definition works.

`dataflow:>stream create demo --definition "twitterstream | file --directory=/someFolder --mode=APPEND --name=demo.txt"`

A couple of things to point out:

1) The `twitterstream` source does not support `--credentials` as an OOTB property. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-twitterstream-source).

2) The `file` sink does not support `--filename` as an OOTB property; you'd have to use `--name` instead. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-file-sink).

Comment: Can you please suggest any demo on hdfs sink ?  I am not getting it done with    `dataflow:>stream create demo --definition "twitterstream | hdfs --directory=hdfs://ipaddress:9000/user/result --file-name=demo` .

Comment: You need to use `--fs-uri=hdfs://ipaddress:9000` property to pass the `NameNode` URI and the directory should be the folder. In your case, `--directory=/user/result`.

Please follow the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-hdfs-sink).